# Alternatives for strrspn and strfind functions(libgen functions in Solaris) in AIX?

Tags: c, gcc, aix

Do we have any alternative for the strrspn and strfind functions(libgen functions in Solaris) for gcc compiler in AIX?

The functionalities are mentioned below -

> `int strfind(const char *s1, const char *s2);`
>  - The strfind() function returns the offset of the first occurrence of the second string, s2, if it is a substring of string s1. If the second string is not a substring of the first string strfind() returns -1.
>
> `char *strrspn(const char *string, const char *cset);`
>  - The strrspn() function trims chartacters from a string. It searches from the end of string for the first character that is not contained in cset. If such a character is found, strrspn() returns a pointer to the next character; otherwise, it returns a pointer to string.

Please help with this?

Comment: `strfind` looks like `strstr`. I don't know anything for `strrspn` from the top of my head

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin (just nitpick, maybe) but `strstr()` returns `char *`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh right, some work is required to transform the call. hence a comment and not an answer =)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I assume it does not hurt to subtract the original pointer from the return value of `strstr()` in order to get the exact same result as `strfind()`'s return value.

Comment: As for `strrspn()`: replace it with a loop and a repeated call to `strspn()` while you reach the end of the string.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant It is not about "hurting", I was suggesting there is no _direct_ alternative in standard `C`. Please correct me if otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing exactly like `strfind` that I know of. but you could implement it using `strstr`:

```
int
strfind (const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
  const char *res = strstr(haystack, needle);
  // if not found, return -1
  if (res == NULL)
    return -1;
  // else return the offset in haystack
  return res - haystack;
}
```

`strrspn` is maybe a bit trickier, but you could do something along these lines:

```
char*
strrspn (const char *string, const char *cset)
{
  size_t len = strlen(strign);
  const char *p = string + len;

  // start from the back, and look for a char not in cset
  while (--p >= string)
    if (NULL == strchr(cset, *p))
      return p;

  return string
}
```

needless to say, these functions are entirely untested and willl likely not work as they stand, but they should give you an idea.